# Select the option for “?” that continues the pattern in each question.

Tags: pattern-recognition

i'm no to sure where to start with these pattern. If they were in an ordinary descending or ascending order it'd be easier. There's a pattern here, What would be the next number after 20? Can anyone assist please

3, -6, 12, 4, 20, ?

Comment: @snulty: $3+8=12$?

Comment: @symplectomorphic good thing it wasn't an answer! :) it's been a long day

Comment: For any number you could find a pattern that would make that number the next .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there exist an infinitely many functions for which $f(1)=3, f(2)=-6, f(3)=12, f(4)=4, f(5)=20$.
Mathematically, any of those functions could define the "pattern" you seek.

The answer you are looking for is probably this:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-next-term-of-the-series-3-6-12-4-20-___